# symfony form CheckboxType inside CollectionType = prototype empty

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to use a `CheckBoxType` in a form inside a `CollectionType` but the prototype only contains the label and no checkbox at all !

This is really weird; I don't understand because the symfony documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html#value) does not mention anything special to do ?

When I click on the button to add a new file I only get the label

What am I missing please?

THE COLLECTION

```
->add('file', CollectionType::class, array(
    'label' => false,
    'entry_type' => FileType::class,
    'error_bubbling' => false,
    'entry_options' => [ 'required' => false, 'error_bubbling' => true, ],
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true
))
```

THE CHECKBOX INSIDE `FILETYPE`

```
->add('main', CheckboxType::class,[
     'label'    => 'Make this one the main picture',
     'required' => false,
]);
```

THE RESULTING PROTOTYPE

```
data-prototype="<div id=\"new_item_group_pictures_itemFile___name__\">    <div class=\"form-item\"><div class=\"form-label\"></div><div class=\"custom-select\"><input type=\"file\" id=\"new_item_group_pictures_itemFile___name___file\" name=\"new_item[group_pictures][itemFile][__name__][file]\" class=\"form-file\" /></div></div>    <div class=\"form-item\"><div class=\"form-label\"><label for=\"new_item_group_pictures_itemFile___name___description\">Description</label></div><input type=\"text\" id=\"new_item_group_pictures_itemFile___name___description\" name=\"new_item[group_pictures][itemFile][__name__][description]\" maxlength=\"255\" class=\"form-input form-text\" /></div>    <div class=\"form-item\"><div class=\"form-label\"><label for=\"new_item_group_pictures_itemFile___name___main\">Make this one the main picture</label></div></div></div>"
```

ENTITY PROPERTY

```
 /**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $main;
```

Comment: Try using 'label' => false inside entry_options's array.

Comment: I tried but no change

Answer (score 1):

you have to render your embeded form collection iterating over it:

```
{% for t in form.file %}
    {{ form_row(t) }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will render each checkbox and you can manipulate them in your view

Normally checkboxType should work fine, but if you want to try another solution you can set your second form to ChoiceType and add expanded (to expand choices like checkboxes) and multiple true.

```
->add('main',  ChoiceType::class,[
     'label'    => 'Make this one the main picture',
     'required' => false,
     'choices' => array(),
     'expanded' => true,
     'multiple' => true
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The label of the collection type should be **true** and when you render the form field of the collection type use **form_widget** instead of **form_row**